# Use of Amari when an adjective is in the negative

Tags: adjectives, negation

I am following a book called "Teach Yourself Japanese", right now I am on using adjectives.

In there, there is an example:

> Igirisu no jamu wa totemo oishii desu.

Which I can understand in terms of structure and rules etc..

But in the book, it says that when an adjective is in the negative, "Amari" must be used. So:

> Igirisu no jamu wa totemo amari oishii desu.

Is there a reason why amari is used? Or can anyone give me some more information about this word?

Comment: Have you learned hiragana or katakana yet?

Comment: Yes I have learned half of the hiragana characters so far, I only started yesterday.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a pair of **polarity items**.  One appears in positive contexts, the other in negative:

> イギリスの　ジャムは　**とても**　おいし**いです**。
>   イギリスの　ジャムは　**あまり**　おいし**くありません**。

Every language has words like these.  For example, in English:

> I like pie, **too**.
>   I don't like pie, **either**.

Here, *too* and *either* are **polarity items**.  In our positive sentence we use *too*, and in our negative sentence we use *either*.  It doesn't work very well if we reverse them:

> ×I like pie, **either**.
>   ×I don't like pie, **too**.

We can see something similar in your Japanese sentences.  **とても** means "to a great degree", similar to English *very*, and in this meaning it appears in positive contexts:

> イギリスの　ジャムは　**とても**　おいし**いです**。
>   English jam tastes **very** good.

On the other hand, **あまり** means "to a low degree", similar to English *not very*, and in this meaning it appears in negative contexts:

> イギリスの　ジャムは　**あまり**　おいし**くありません**。
>   English jam does**n't** taste **very** good.

Your book probably didn't mean for you to put them together into one sentence.

Comment: thank you for this, I am at work so I tried forming the second sentence myself, perhaps the book didn't.

Could you recommend some things I could practice with adjectives? or any places that will test my knowledge of them?

Comment: So negative context here means the negation of something, i.e. "not ~"? I see that it is so in the Wikipedia page you linked. It's unfortunate that my brain interprets the word "negative context" in another way, i.e. I associate "negative context" with words like 怖い and 怒っている.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest meaning vs　とても/totemo ("very"), used in many first text books, is "not very".

This gives us:

> "not very good" for amari yokunai/あまりよくない

and

> "not very interesting" for amari omoshirokunai/あまり面白くない

and even

> "not very bad" for amari warukunai/あまり悪くない

The best way to practice is to buy a text book (which you can probably trust) or possibly find a website with a few exercises.

Answer (score 0):

Things aren't completely +/- here. Variations on

> あまりにもおいしい
> あまりのおしさ

are both perfectly fine; even common.
Or how about

> とてもできない

Comment: It's true that they're not always a PPI and NPI respectively, which is why I wrote "in this meaning".  Both words are licensed in various contexts with different meanings.

Answer (score -2):

In very simple terms:

"Amari," used with a negative, simply means "quite."

"amari yokunai" = "quite bad."

"amari omoshirokunai" = "quite uninteresting"

Comment: No, that's quite the opposite of what it means.

Comment: You could say amari means "quite" or "very" in the positive sense, but when used with a negative it gets interpreted "(not) (very good)," rather than "(very) (not good)."